# Crash .net 3.5 heap-corruption after obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, crash, obfuscation

After two month of investigation with Microsoft I request for your help with one of the most hard exception that we gen get- heap corruption in .net.
We facing with crashes in our .net 3.5 application after 3-4 hours of running.
We we try to invistigate the dump we can see that the GC falling one of the thread:

```
     ID OSID        ThreadOBJ     State   GC     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count APT Exception
   0    1 160c 0000000000521270      6020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 STA
   2    2 1620 0000000000527960      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
   5    3 163c 000000001cc75280   200b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
   6    4 164c 000000001cc75850   180b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker) System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (00000000039d7998)
   7    5 1650 000000001cc763f0    80a220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
   8    6 1654 000000001cc769c0   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
   9    7 1658 000000001cc76f90   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  10    8 165c 000000001cc77560   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  12    9 1664 000000001cc79270       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 Ukn
  15    b 150c 000000001cc7a9b0      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     1 MTA
XXXX    f    0 000000001cc7c6c0      9820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  16    e 1530 000000001cc7c0f0      b220 Disabled 0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     4 MTA (GC)
  17    c 1528 000000001cc7b550      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  18   10 1538 000000001cc7af80      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  19   11 153c 000000001f1d5ca0      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0000000008534500)
  20   12 1568 000000001f1d6270      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException (00000000038e70a8)
  21   13 1570 000000001f1d6840      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException (00000000038e7be8)
  22   14 1574 000000001f1d6e10      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  23   15 152c 000000001f1d73e0      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  24   17 148c 0000000028877250   180b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  25   1a 13b0 00000000288783c0      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  26   16 16fc 0000000027978ca0      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA
  27   77 1038 000000001cc7bb20   8801220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) System.IO.FileNotFoundException (00000000062573a8)
  28   71 14ac 000000002797b550   880b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000000050eaf0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException (0000000007168c90)
```

The call stack usually is on string operation like contact:

```
0:016> kpL
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`2bbd9ad8 000007fe`fcd510dc ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject(void)+0xa
00000000`2bbd9ae0 000007fe`f24c3a69 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx(void * hHandle = 0x00000000`00004e20, unsigned long dwMilliseconds = 0xffffffff, int bAlertable = 0n0)+0x79
00000000`2bbd9b80 000007fe`f24c3c5e mscorwks!ClrWaitForSingleObject(void * handle = 0x00000000`00000000, unsigned long timeout = 0x1050)+0x2d
00000000`2bbd9bd0 000007fe`f24b6978 mscorwks!RunWatson(void * hWatsonSharedMemory = 0x05300000`0000018e, void * hEventAlive = 0x00000000`00000002, void * hEventDone = 0x00000000`1c810000, void * hMutex = 0x00000000`00001890)+0x1ca
00000000`2bbda160 000007fe`f28dbfcf mscorwks!DoFaultReportWorker(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x00000000`2bbda9d8, class TypeOfReportedError tore = class TypeOfReportedError, class Thread * pThread = 0x00000000`2bbdb3f0, unsigned long dwThreadID = 0x19f8)+0x79c
00000000`2bbda9b0 000007fe`f24ea48b mscorwks!DoFaultReport(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x000007fe`f22b0420, class TypeOfReportedError tore = class TypeOfReportedError)+0x9f
00000000`2bbdaa20 000007fe`f28fbda9 mscorwks!WatsonLastChance(class Thread * pThread = 0x00000000`2bbdb0b0, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x00000000`2746afc0, class TypeOfReportedError tore = class TypeOfReportedError)+0x47
00000000`2bbdaa90 000007fe`f28fc0be mscorwks!EEPolicy::LogFatalError(unsigned int exitCode = 0, unsigned int64 address = 0, unsigned short * pszMessage = 0x00000000`1cc7c0f0, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x000007fe`f24eb249)+0x2f9
00000000`2bbdb210 000007fe`f23423e9 mscorwks!EEPolicy::HandleFatalError(unsigned int exitCode = 0x1c, unsigned int64 address = 0xffffffff`ffffffff, unsigned short * pszMessage = 0xffffffff`000000f8, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x6e
00000000`2bbdb260 000007fe`f238b390 mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase3(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x00000000`2bbdcc60)+0xcd
00000000`2bbdb2a0 000007fe`f238b597 mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase2(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x30
00000000`2bbdb310 000007fe`f23422ee mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x00000000`000000cd)+0xff
00000000`2bbdb390 00000000`76d9a5db mscorwks!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerShim(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo = 0x00000000`1d870158)+0x42
00000000`2bbdb3d0 00000000`76d98e62 ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers(struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord = 0x00000000`09d28298, struct _CONTEXT * ContextRecord = 0x000007fe`0000007f, unsigned long Index = 0x1d872fd0)+0xa8
00000000`2bbdb440 00000000`76dd1248 ntdll!RtlDispatchException(struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord = 0x00000000`00000000, struct _CONTEXT * ContextRecord = 0x000007fe`f23bad43)+0x22
00000000`2bbdbb20 000007fe`f27890c8 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch(void)+0x2e
00000000`2bbdc0e0 000007fe`f23ee762 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::mark_object_simple(unsigned char ** po = 0x00000000`2bbddfd0)+0x198
00000000`2bbdc150 000007fe`f23d91e1 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::Promote(class Object ** object = 0x00000000`09d28298, struct ScanContext * sc = 0x00000000`2bbdd380, unsigned long flags = 0x2bbdc2e4)+0x52
00000000`2bbdc1c0 000007fe`f23bb299 mscorwks!GcEnumObject(void * pData = 0x00000000`2bbdc6e0, class Object ** pObj = 0x000007fe`f23d9010, unsigned long flags = 0x2bbddfd0)+0x1d1
00000000`2bbdc220 000007fe`f23c1ab5 mscorwks!GcInfoDecoder::EnumerateLiveSlots(struct REGDISPLAY * pRD = 0x00000000`2bbdd380, bool reportScratchSlots = false, unsigned int inputFlags = 0x2c, <function> * pCallBack = 0x000007fe`f23d9010, void * hCallBack = 0x00000000`2bbddfd0)+0x5d9
00000000`2bbdc650 000007fe`f23c66e3 mscorwks!EECodeManager::EnumGcRefs(struct REGDISPLAY * pRD = 0x00000000`2c5ae5b8, class EECodeInfo * pCodeInfo = 0x000007fe`93408cb6, unsigned int flags = 0x2c5ae6f0, <function> * pCallBack = 0x000007fe`f23d9010, void * hCallBack = 0x00000000`2bbddfd0)+0xc5
00000000`2bbdc9d0 000007fe`f23c5665 mscorwks!GcStackCrawlCallBack(class CrawlFrame * pCF = 0x00000000`2f51e938, void * pData = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x1b3
00000000`2bbdca90 000007fe`f23b24e9 mscorwks!Thread::StackWalkFramesEx(struct REGDISPLAY * pRD = 0x00000000`00000000, <function> * pCallback = 0x00000000`27978100, void * pData = 0x00000000`00000500, unsigned int flags = 0x500, class Frame * pStartFrame = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x835
00000000`2bbdce80 000007fe`f23e847e mscorwks!Thread::StackWalkFrames(<function> * pCallback = 0x000007fe`f23d2d1e, void * pData = 0x00000000`00000000, unsigned int flags = 0xfcd518da, class Frame * pStartFrame = 0x00000000`00000000)+0xb9
00000000`2bbddf90 000007fe`f23914a4 mscorwks!CNameSpace::GcScanRoots(<function> * fn = 0x00000000`00080101, int condemned = 0n2857451, int max_gen = 0n-2, struct ScanContext * sc = 0x00000000`00000000, class GCHeap * Hp = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x1be
00000000`2bbde050 000007fe`f283d3b6 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::mark_phase(int condemned_gen_number = 0n733864200, int mark_only_p = 0n0)+0xd4
00000000`2bbde0e0 000007fe`f283dcb4 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::gc1(void)+0x86
00000000`2bbde130 000007fe`f268c056 mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect(int n = 0n5260944, int concurrent_p = 0n0)+0x2a4
00000000`2bbde190 000007fe`f283dec0 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration(unsigned int gen = 0xffffffff, WKS::gc_reason reason = reason_alloc_soh (0n0))+0x1e6
00000000`2bbde1e0 000007fe`f23c8b8d mscorwks!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space(struct alloc_context * acontext = 0x00000000`1cc7c158, unsigned int64 size = 0xa0, int gen_number = 0n-113214793)+0x180
00000000`2bbde2c0 000007fe`f23cbb5e mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc(struct alloc_context * acontext = 0x00000000`04f7f620, unsigned int64 size = 0x9a, unsigned long flags = 0x41)+0x6d
00000000`2bbde2f0 000007fe`f28984f3 mscorwks!SlowAllocateString(unsigned long cchArrayLength = 0x2bbde3c8)+0x7e
00000000`2bbde370 000007fe`dc7a2ff2 mscorwks!FramedAllocateString(unsigned long stringLength = 0x40)+0xd3
00000000`2bbde530 000007fe`935852ca mscorlib_ni!System.String.Concat(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x42
00000000`2bbde580 000007fe`92caadf8 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Helper.PathHelper.IsSubFolderOf(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x4a
00000000`2bbde5c0 000007fe`93720691 System_Core!System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0xb8
00000000`2bbde640 000007fe`93720562 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Changes.ChangedItemsTree.a(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x81
00000000`2bbde690 000007fe`93720341 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Changes.ChangedItemsTree.a(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x42
00000000`2bbde6e0 000007fe`9371fe1d Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Changes.ChangedItemsTree.c(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x31
00000000`2bbde760 000007fe`9371fbea Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Changes.ChangedItemsTree.Insert(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0xad
00000000`2bbde840 000007fe`9371f125 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Manager.ChangeQueue.Enqueue(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x1fa
00000000`2bbde8d0 000007fe`9371ebc4 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Entities.WildcardFilteringChangeQueue.Enqueue(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x55
00000000`2bbde910 000007fe`9371eadf Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Entities.SelectiveSyncingChangeQueue.Enqueue(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x64
00000000`2bbde960 000007fe`9371e82c Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Entities.ChangeQueueDecorators.PausePathChangeQueue.Enqueue(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x7f
00000000`2bbde9b0 000007fe`9371e70a Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Entities.MergeBreakingChangeQueue.Enqueue(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0xfc
00000000`2bbdea40 000007fe`9371c701 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Entities.ChangeQueueDecorators.UnavailableResourceChangeQueue.Enqueue(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x1a
00000000`2bbdea70 000007fe`9371a0c8 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Workers.ServerChangesPoller.a(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x291
00000000`2bbdeb70 000007fe`93408592 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Workers.ServerChangesPoller.a(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x6b8
00000000`2bbdec00 000007fe`93407ba4 Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Workers.ServerChangesPoller.b(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x2e2
00000000`2bbdec90 000007fe`dc7a2bcb Varonis_Scf_Client_Sync!Varonis.Scf.Client.Sync.Workers.ServerChangesPoller.ThreadRoutine(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0xa4
00000000`2bbded20 000007fe`dc83aaad mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x9b
00000000`2bbded70 000007fe`f24fabd2 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(<HRESULT 0x80004001>)+0x4d
00000000`2bbdedc0 000007fe`f2397343 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker(void)+0x82
00000000`2bbdee10 000007fe`f28d9c91 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler(void * pSrcEnd = 0x00000000`2bbdef48, unsigned int numStackSlots = 0, unsigned int64 dwRegTypeMap = 0, unsigned int fpReturnSize = 1, void * pTarget = 0x000007fe`dc7538b8, int fCriticalCall = 0n0)+0xd3
00000000`2bbdeeb0 000007fe`f2490071 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr(unsigned char * pTarget = 0x00000000`2bbdfe50 "\k???", class MetaSig * pMetaSigOrig = 0x00000000`2bbdf630, unsigned int64 * pArguments = 0x000007fe`dc8f3680, int fIsStatic = 0n0, int fCriticalCall = 0n0)+0x2b1
00000000`2bbdf0f0 000007fe`f233a988 mscorwks!ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker(void * ptr = 0x00000000`00000001)+0x191
00000000`2bbdf410 000007fe`f236c355 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner(struct ManagedThreadCallState * pCallState = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x2c
00000000`2bbdf460 000007fe`f2455955 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle(struct ManagedThreadCallState * pCallState = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x9d
00000000`2bbdf530 000007fe`f24b941d mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter(struct ManagedThreadCallState * pCallState = 0x00000000`2bbdf590)+0x31
00000000`2bbdf570 000007fe`f232f72f mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD(struct ADID pAppDomain = struct ADID, <function> * pTarget = 0x00000000`00000000, void * args = 0x00000005`0000003e, UnhandledExceptionLocation filterType = 0n22 (No matching enumerant))+0x35
00000000`2bbdf5d0 000007fe`f2338128 mscorwks!ThreadNative::KickOffThread(void * pass = 0x00000002`00000000)+0xd3
00000000`2bbdf6b0 00000000`76c7652d mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc(void * arg = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x78
00000000`2bbdfe80 00000000`76dac541 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk(unsigned long RunProcessInit = 0, <function> * StartAddress = 0x00000000`00000000, void * Argument = 0x00000000`00000000)+0xd
00000000`2bbdfeb0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart(<function> * StartAddress = 0x00000000`00000000, void * Argument = 0x00000000`00000000)+0x1d
```

In the begging we was thinking that is known issue with the Gc:
[How to: Disable Concurrent Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

But that solution didn't help.

We went through all our unmanage call (we were thinking that is heap corruption from unsafe call), but it didn't help either. Also we call to GC collect after each call to unsafe code to get closer to the problem, but that solution also seems not to work.

In the last days we noticed that the crash only happen on obfuscation code, I tried to looking for similar problem that realted to obfuscation and heap currption but I didn't find any. Can you suggest what can cause to that kind of problem? 
Some of our dll's are strong sign, but non of them are obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some obfuscators not only renaming the symbols names, but also "optimizing" the code and making actual logic changes and refactoring.

For example, some make some classes "sealed" to gain speed, some others refactor the code by adding/removing methods in order to obfuscate more, others store literals somewhere else, others refactor the code adding dependency injection so symbols are not tightly coupled and it makes more difficult to read it, others replace some static code with "dynamic real-time compiled code routines", etc.

So, might be ending up with a bunch of code logic you didn't code for.

Be careful with the obfuscator settings, some of them could be the ones giving you trouble.

Comment: I already know that,  but we have to use obfuscation. Can you think about settings in the obfuscation that may cause to heap corruption?

Comment: Just an idea, but the first thing I'd do is try disabling obfuscation for and around unsafe code. It's possible that this is the place where obfuscation does not work well enough

Comment: Well, every time I have issues like this, I usually do something similar to a "binary search" when troubleshooting.

For example, if you have the settings "A, B, C, D", enable "A, B" and see if the issue happens; if not, disable "A, B" and enable "C, D". If the issue happens with "C, D", then try only "C" or "D".